# Distorted sound, Intermittent slow internet on Feodra & Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, audio, fedora

I have a core i7 machine on which I have dual booted Ubuntu 10.10 and Fedora 14. I am facing a weird problem on both the Linux distributions. Currently, I am facing three major problems which are causing me to use my laptop instead of this machine.

1. Most of the times the sound gets distorted ( like the tempo is very slow and some cracks), but some other times it just works fine. ( I experienced this on both Ubuntu and Fedora)
2. Internet at times is very fast and works great, but suddenly it slows down and takes a whole lot time to load. sometimes it just never gets fast.
3. The low resolution flash videos, gets this very weird high pitch sound

Also, I noticed ( I don't think there is a relation between the two or is there?) that whenever the internet is slow, the sound is also distorted and when internet is fast sound works great.

The intermittent nature of the problem is making it difficult to debug.

Any thoughts on these?

Below is my lspci output for your information -

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub to ESI Port (rev 13)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 13)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 13)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev 13)
00:14.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub System Management Registers (rev 13)
00:14.1 PIC: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub GPIO and Scratch Pad Registers (rev 13)
00:14.2 PIC: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub Control Status and RAS Registers (rev 13)
00:14.3 PIC: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub Throttle Registers (rev 13)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567V-2 Gigabit Network Connection
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
00:1a.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Port 2
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 3
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 4
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 90)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JIR (ICH10R) LPC Interface Controller
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 SATA RAID Controller
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller
02:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362/JMB363 Serial ATA Controller (rev 03)
02:00.1 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362/JMB363 Serial ATA Controller (rev 03)
04:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 220] (rev a2)
07:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-Core Registers (rev 05)
ff
```

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit Linux?

Comment: 64-bit Linux - core i7 processor

Answer (score 1):

It's probably related to this (libc 2.12.90 included memcpy changes, and they expose latent bugs on 64 bit systems):

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638477

Unfortunately that thread's become a religious debate, and the upstream bug was apparently refused.

Comment: well they have two choices. roll back libc until adobe fix the bug, or break everything and wait till adobe fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

some streaming sites the audio plays overly fast for me...not sure what that's about, probably poor syncing and keyframing.  it is rare on my box though.  i compile my own multimedia stuff.  alternately, how many apps are trying to grab alsa sound? one of the could be changing the bitrate expected by the card.

the cracks you referred to usually indicate that something is releasing and re-grabbing the sound card. i had this problem with older versions of some players, but since using latest ffmpeg/mplayer/respective moz-plugins/flashplugin.so everything is fine for me with standard hda intel driver.

can't address the wireless thing at all (it doesn't show up in lspci)...need more info on that one to see if it's just a buggy chipset/driver combination - probably the case.